# Make grid items overlap

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to achieve a css grid pattern where the header is overlaying the next row.

I have added a snippet of my code with the header on top, the attached image should show you what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks

[image]

```css
body { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header"
    "nav article ads"
    "footer footer footer";
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;  
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  }  
/* Stack the layout on small devices/viewports. */
@media all and (max-width: 575px) {
  body { 
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header"
      "article"
      "ads"
      "nav"
      "footer";
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px 1fr 70px;  
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
 }
}
header, footer, article, nav, div {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: gold;
  }
#pageHeader {
  grid-area: header;
  }
#pageFooter {
  grid-area: footer;
  }
#mainArticle { 
  grid-area: article;      
  }
#mainNav { 
  grid-area: nav; 
  }
#siteAds { 
  grid-area: ads; 
  }
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">Header</header>
<article id="mainArticle">Article</article>
<nav id="mainNav">Nav</nav>
<div id="siteAds">Ads</div>
<footer id="pageFooter">Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the [**`grid-template-areas`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-template-areas-property) property to arrange the layout with ASCII art.

```
body { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header"
    "nav article ads"
    "footer footer footer";
  ...
}
```

This method works fine for grid areas that don't overlap.

But strings cannot overlap in the code, so this method cannot be used to overlay grid areas.

In other words, `"header header header"` and `"nav article ads"` can be above and below each other on the X and Y axes, but not the Z axis.

To make grid areas overlap you'll need another method.

CSS Grid provides [**line-based placement**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement) as an alternative to `grid-template-areas`.

Line-based placement means, in essence, using this following properties to determine a grid item's size and location:

- `grid-row-start`
- `grid-row-end`
- `grid-column-start`
- `grid-column-end`

and the [shorthands](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands):

- `grid-column`
- `grid-row`

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
  grid-gap: 10px;       /* shorthand for grid-row-gap and grid-column-gap */
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
#pageHeader {
  grid-row: 1;          /* see notes below */
  grid-column: 1 / 4;   /* see notes below */
  background-color: crimson;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: .5;
}
#pageFooter {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
#mainArticle {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
#mainNav {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
#siteAds {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
}
header, footer, article, nav, div {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">Header</header>
<article id="mainArticle">Article</article>
<nav id="mainNav">Nav</nav>
<div id="siteAds">Ads</div>
<footer id="pageFooter">Footer</footer>
```

The `grid-row` and `grid-column` properties control the location and size of grid items.

- `grid-column: 1 / 4` means the grid item will span from grid column lines one to four (i.e, the item will span across the first, second and third columns)
- `grid-row: 3` means the grid item will be located on row three (from grid row line 3 to `auto`, which is applied by default when the second value is omitted.)

With this method of positioning grid items, you can easily make them overlap.

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84ter3r8/1/)

Answer (score -1):

To achieve what you want to achieve you could use multiple solutions

**Solution one** 
Solution one consists of using a `position: fixed` CSS styling on the header. 
Note: This will make the header stay on top and stay there when you're scrolling down. if you would give the header an `opacity` attribute of lets say 0.8 and on hover an `opacity` of 1 it will have a great affect.

**Solution one example**

```css
    body {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
                "header header header"
                "nav article ads"
                "footer footer footer";
        grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;
        grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
        grid-row-gap: 10px;
        grid-column-gap: 10px;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
    }
    /* Stack the layout on small devices/viewports. */
    @media all and (max-width: 575px) {
        body {
            grid-template-areas:
                    "header"
                    "article"
                    "ads"
                    "nav"
                    "footer";
            grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px 1fr 70px;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        }
    }
    header, footer, article, nav, div {
        padding: 1.2em;
        background: gold;
    }
    #pageHeader {
        grid-area: header;
        z-index: 1999;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: orange;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    #pageHeader:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #pageFooter {
        grid-area: footer;
    }
    #mainArticle {
        grid-area: article;
    }
    #mainNav {
        grid-area: nav;
        height: 2000px;
    }
    #siteAds {
        grid-area: ads;
    }
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">Header</header>
<article id="mainArticle">Article</article>
<nav id="mainNav">Nav</nav>
<div id="siteAds">Ads</div>
<footer id="pageFooter">Footer</footer>
```

**Solution two** 
Solution two consists of using a more 'not liked' way of using CSS. it consists of using negative margins on all the content under the header. by lets say adding a `<div id="main-content">` on all the content under the header and adding a negative margin of lets say `margin-top: -100px;` attribute on this div.

**Solution two example**

```css
    body {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas:
                "header header header"
                "nav article ads"
                "footer footer footer";
        grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;
        grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
        grid-row-gap: 10px;
        grid-column-gap: 10px;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
    }
    /* Stack the layout on small devices/viewports. */
    @media all and (max-width: 575px) {
        body {
            grid-template-areas:
                    "header"
                    "article"
                    "ads"
                    "nav"
                    "footer";
            grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px 1fr 70px;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        }
    }
    header, footer, article, nav, div {
        padding: 1.2em;
        background: gold;
    }
    #pageHeader {
        grid-area: header;
        background-color: orange;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    #pageFooter {
        grid-area: footer;
    }
    #mainArticle {
        margin-top: -100px;
        grid-area: article;
    }
    #mainNav {
        margin-top: -100px;
        grid-area: nav;
    }
    #siteAds {
        margin-top: -100px;
        grid-area: ads;
    }
```

```html
<header id="pageHeader">Header</header>
<article id="mainArticle">Article</article>
<nav id="mainNav">Nav</nav>
<div id="siteAds">Ads</div>
<footer id="pageFooter">Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one is correct but like you not happy with the way it's done. I think there is a better way of achieving this with the new css grid system possibly using span and z-index but i can't figure out how.